# Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}xg(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, limits

$g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$ is continuous and the Riemann integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent. Find the following limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}xg(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Since the only thing you know something about is $\int_0^\infty g(x)dx$, perhaps an integration-by-parts could give you something to work with, by removing $x$ from inside the integral? Have you tried that?

Comment: First take a few simple functions for $g$ so that you can explicitly evaluate the integral. That allows you to make an educated guess what the result should be. Then try to prove it.

Comment: Informally, since $\int_0^\infty g\,dx$ converges, $g$ decays faster than $\frac 1 x$ (whose integral diverges), hence $xg(x)$ decays towards zero and its average decays towards zero as well.

Comment: Four questions so far, none with any personal input. Please modify your modus operandi.

Answer (score 2):

Define $G(x) = \int_x^\infty g(t) dt$. Then $G'(x) = -g(x)$ and
$\lim_{x \to \infty} G(x) = 0$. Integration by parts gives
$$
\frac 1n \int_0^n xg(x) \, dx = -G(n) + \frac 1n\int_0^n G(x) \, dx \, .
$$
The first term on the rhs has the limit zero. Now show that
the second term has the limit zero as well.

For every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $K > 0$ such that
$|G(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $x \ge K$. Then for $n > K$
$$
 \left| \frac 1n\int_0^n G(x) \, dx \right| \le 
 \frac 1n  \left| \int_0^K G(x) \, dx \right| + \frac{(n -K)\varepsilon}n 
$$
and therefore
$$
0 \le \limsup_{n \to \infty}  \left| \frac 1n\int_0^n G(x) \, dx  \right| \le \varepsilon \, .
$$
Since  $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, it follows that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n\int_0^n G(x) \, dx = 0
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \int_0^n xg(x) \, dx = 0 \, .
$$
(Note that the non-negativity of $g$ was not needed in these arguments.)

Comment: Can you generalize this approach to $\frac 1 n \int_0^n f(x)g(x)\,dx \to 0$ for any $f$, s.t. $\int \frac 1 {f(x)}\,dx$ diverges at $\infty$ ($g$ has the same constraints)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For every c>0, There exist n such that $\int_n^{+\infty}g(x)<c/2$, let $m>n$, $1/m\int_0^mxg(x)dx= \int_0^n(x/m)g(x)dx+\int_n^m(x/m)g(x)$.

$\int_0^n(x/m)g(x)dx<\int_0^nn/mg(x)dx<n/m\int_0^{+\infty}g(x)$

$\int_n^m(x/m)g(x)<\int_n^{+\infty}g(x)<c/2$

there exists N such that m>N implies that $n/m\int_0^{+\infty}g(x)<c/2$
thus for m>N, $1/m\int_0^mxg(x)dx<c$, we deduce that the limit is zero.

the limit is 0